# How to find an object nested in multi-level collection

Tags: c#, ienumerable, traversal

Lets say I have a `List<Family>` and each Family has a `List<Child>`.

When I encounter a `Child` object in my code, how can I determine if the child is a part of any family?

**Pseudo code:**

```
If Child not in any family
    // Do something with child
```

**Update:**

**Example models:**

```
class Family
{
  public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
  // Properties
}

class Child
{
  // Properties
}
```

**Example ViewModel:**

```
class FamilyViewModel
{
  public List<Family> Families {get;set;}

  public bool ChildHasFamily(Child child)
  {
     // Determine if child is in any family or not
  } 
}
```

Comment: What do you classes looks like?

Comment: Why `ChildHasFamily` "returns" _void_ instead of `bool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this isn't all that clean to me. I think your `Child` should have `Family` property to make things easier. If I understand correctly, your view model has a list of family which in turn contains a list of childs. When you receive a list of child, you want to know if it is in one of your family:

```
class FamilyViewModel
{
  public List<Family> Families {get;set;}

  public void ChildHasFamily(Child child)
  {
      var hasFamily = Families.SelectMany(f => f.Children)
                              .Contains(child);
  } 
}
```

Note that this will do an object reference comparison. If Child implement `IEquatable<Child>`, it will work out of the box. If not, you can use:

```
class FamilyViewModel
{
  public List<Family> Families {get;set;}

  public void ChildHasFamily(Child child)
  {
      var hasFamily = Families.SelectMany(f => f.Children)
                              .Any(c => c.Name == child.Name);
  } 
}
```

Replace the `Where` predicate for your identity comparison.

Comment: Found your solution to be the cleanest and closest to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use following recursive `Traverse` method which uses deferred execution.

Then it's easy as:

```
IEnumerable<Family> familiesOfChild = families.Traverse(f => f.Children)
    .Where(c => c.Equals(yourChild));
if(!familiesOfChild.Any())
{
    // oh, what a poor child
}
```

Here is the extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> fnRecurse)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;

        IEnumerable<T> seqRecurse = fnRecurse(item);
        if (seqRecurse != null)
        {
            foreach (T itemRecurse in Traverse(seqRecurse, fnRecurse))
            {
                yield return itemRecurse;
            }
        }
    }
}
```